# How to remove close button, created by and last modified by from display form of list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, display-form, hide-elements

Using script editor/content editor web-part on the display form of list, I am able to get the list item to print.

However it also prints close button, created by and last modified by from the display form of list.

Any help on how to hide or remove this from the print?

Answer (score 1):

We can add the following style into script editor web part in display form to achieve it.

```
<style>
.ms-formtoolbar{
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Or using jQuery code below to remove it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".ms-formtoolbar").remove();   
}); 
</script>
```